# Why do cookies and sessions need to come before any HTML?

Tags: php, session, cookies

And additionally, why the white space sensitivity? If JavaScript can add cookies after HTML has loaded, then I would guess there is something fundamentally different about how they do it, but I can't figure out even a good guess as to why.

Comment: You should read an introduction to HTTP, the protocol that is used to transfer HTML.

Comment: It's required by the [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol). Cookies are set in the headers, and headers **MUST** come before the body contents. JS isn't using HTTP for cookies. It's already running inside the browser and can directly set/manipulate cookies. The server isn't running in the browser. it can only set cookies via `Cookie` directives in the header of its responses.

Comment: @MarcB That *must* of yours is only true for HTTP/1.0. Chunked transfer encoding allows headers to be sent after the file's body.

Comment: Thanks for all the help - that cleared up my curiosity, specifically the difference between how the 2 languages set cookies.  I apologize for the question being too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP responses consist of a header and an (optional depending on the header) body.

Cookies are set with HTTP headers.

HTML documents (any any other actual content) are sent in the body.

The header has to be sent before the body. This can either be done by:

- running the code to output them before the code to output the body
- buffering the output of the PHP program until it has finished running

---

> And additionally, why the white space sensitivity?

Whitespace isn't special in HTTP response bodies. It is output like any other content.

---

> If JavaScript can add cookies after HTML has loaded, then I would guess there is something fundamentally different about how they do it

They don't use HTTP headers to set them.

Comment: This answer is incomplete. It is possible to send headers after the body using HTTP/1.1's chunked encoding. The interesting question is why PHP does not allow that. My guess is that they either don't know, or that they want to ensure the same behaviour on all platforms, also those that do not support HTTP/1.1 or are using CGI, which also forces headers to be sent first. (But the latter would be unusual for PHP.)

Answer (score 0):

A WWW server sends data to your browser in parts. First part is some text commonly known as `HTTP Headers`. They define type, size, language, encoding of content, server sends also some information on itself. Cookies are sent here too, because this is place for "off-site" informations.

Sessions are a little different. They are server side. So you need to declare session before server starts to render content and send it to client browser. Another reason for it is that your session identifier is... a cookie! So yes, session won't work without cookies.

Cookies are client side (browser side) little text files. JavaScript is client-side (browser side) scripting that works within your browser. So it's not using HTTP to contact with website page you actually watch. There is no need to use HTTP Headers and stuff. If a program runs on your computer it's much better and easier to just modify these files on computer, isn't it?

That's why JavaScript is not using HTTP Headers to modify cookie files. It's just informing your browser that it wants to modify this and that, and browser does that.

More info in [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php)

Comment: "Cookies are client side (browser side) little text files." — No. A browser might *store* the data for a cookie in a little text file, but that's an implementation detail. Cookies are pieces of data exchanged between HTTP servers and clients.